# Desired Indentation for Enumerate Environment

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I'm trying to use enumitem with the \newlist command to create an enumerate-like environment for this:

[image]

I have tried to use the documentation for enumitem to do this and only managed to come up with this:

```
\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercises]{label=\textbf{Aufgabe \arabic*.},leftmargin=*}
```

It correctly produces the "Aufgabe x." numbering which starts at the correct position, but the text after that is not indented as desired:

[image]

I've tried doing it with itemindent but didn't manage to get it to the same position as the label starts. Also, if I then create another enumerate environment inside this one (for a), b) etc.), the indentation is screwed up too.

How can I get this environment (and the one nested inside) to work as intended?

Comment: Use `\setlist[exercises]{label=\textbf{Aufgabe arabic*.}, wide=0pt}`.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks, this works for the first level perfectly. What would I do for the second level? I used `\setlist[exercises,2]{label=\alph*),leftmargin=*,labelindent=-0.14cm}` but seeing your solution for the first level, I'm sure there is a more elegant (and precise) method.

Comment: If you want the left margin of the second level to be the same as the text margin, `wide=0pt` again.

Comment: @Bernard: Please transfer your comments into an answer to kick this question from the list of the unanswered ones ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments: adding the option `wide=0pt` will work at all levels, e.g.

```
\setlist[exercises]{label=\textbf{Aufgabe arabic*.}, wide=0pt}
```